# Vue.use() is throwing "Cannot read property 'use' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

**Attempt 1**

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store/store'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    patients: []
  }
});
```

**Attempt 1 Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at eval (store.js?07a4:4)
    at Module../src/store/store.js (app.js:1342)
```

**Attempt 2**

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store/store'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    patients: []
  }
});
```

**Attempt 2 Error**

```
vuex.esm.js?94ea:135 Uncaught Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?94ea:135)
    at new Store (vuex.esm.js?94ea:380)
    at eval (store.js?07a4:6)
```

I created a Vue application using Vue CLI. I am trying to implement Vuex. I have followed numerous tutorials (usually set up 2 different ways). When using a debugger, I was able to stop before it read "Vue.use(Vuex)". Logging Vue at this point returns undefined. I believe my imports are correct but do not know if I am missing something crucial. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** The only difference between Attempt 1 and 2 is I removed "Vue.use(Vuex)" on Attempt 2.

Answer (score 8):

You're using vuex 3 syntax with Vue 3 which is compatible with vuex 4 that has the following syntax :

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state: {
    patients: []
  }
})
export default store;
```

then use the exported store in the main.js :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store/store'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

**[Vuex 4 docs](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/)**

**[Vue.js 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/)**

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast! Unfortunately, this brings me back to

store.js?07a4:4 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (store.js?07a4:4)
    at Module../src/store/store.js (app.js:1342)

Comment: i'm sure that you've installed vuex 3, please share the package.json file to confirm

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-responsive-components": "^0.2.3"
  }

Comment: in CLI try out `npm uninstall vuex` then `npm install vuex@next`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get this working by uninstalling my VueX (3.6)

```
npm uninstall vuex
```

and installing the VueX (4.0 alpha)

```
npm i vuex@4.0.0-alpha.1
```

The reason for this error was because I was using 2 different syntax methods from different versions.

Thanks for everyone's help!

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store/store'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

// Create a new store instance.
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      patients: []
    }
  }
})

export default store;
```

Comment: You should accept the other answer because it contains the details that you provided here