# It there another way to use "export default new Vuex.Store" on Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, export, vuex

I have problem with using commit like is described here. Probably problem is in that I use `export default new Vuex.Store`.

Here is my `index.js` file, i unfortunately have : `warning`  `in ./src/store/index.js "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'` where I use Vuex and I want to call commit:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

import state from "./state";
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from'./mutations';
import * as actions from './actions';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327647/8172857

Comment: @boussadjra-brahim Thanks for get back, but it even me : `store' is defined but never used` while I use it in `export default new Vuex.store({
...`

Comment: The code in question is for Vue 2, but the question title asks about Vue 3. Which version are you actually using? Also, the warning you mention is about a `store` variable (lowercase). That is not the same as `Vuex.Store`.

Comment: @tony19 hi, i use Vue 3.0 version & i supposed it the same thing (store) but i thing now it maybe the : 'default' cause him the problem

Comment: That code would not work in Vue 3. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?